# MYSQL ERROR NEED advice

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE TableNameHere (
  Home TEXT,
  Height INT,
  Weight INT,
  SignatureMoves TEXT,
  Biography TEXT
  );

INSERT INTO TableNameHere (Home, Height, Weight, SignatureMoves, Biography)
  VALUES ('', '', '', '', '');

Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'Height' at row 1
```

I'm not sure what is the problem

Comment: MySQL tells you everything - you cannot add string value into integer field.  Emtpy space is also a string, so for integer fields put NULL instead of ''

Comment: Dont create a record without any data in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NULL` for numeric fields if you want empty data there:

```
INSERT INTO TableNameHere 
   (Home, Height, Weight, SignatureMoves, Biography) 
VALUES 
   ('', NULL, NULL, '', '');
```